# Java: Trying to create a database that stores

Tags: java, database

```
package student; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Student
{                        
    private Name name;
    String idNUM, course;

     public Student(Name n, String idNum){
        this.name = n;
        this.idNUM = idNum;        
    }
    public Name getName(){
        return name;
    }   
    public String getId(){
        return idNUM;
    }     
}



package student;
public class StudentCourse
{
   Student studInfo, studentInfo;
   String studentCourses, studentCourse;


    StudentCourse(String  sc)
    {       
        studentCourses = sc;
    }

    public String getCourses(){
        return studentCourses;
    }
}


package student;

public class StudentAccounts 
{
   private Student stud;
   private String addedClass;   
   String courses;

    public StudentAccounts (Student s, String course)
    {
      stud = s;          
      courses = course;
    }
    public Student getStudent()
    {
      return stud;
    }
    public void insertClass(String cla)
    {
      courses = cla;
    }
    public String getCourses()
    {
      return courses;
    }  
}
```

Sorry for posting a lot of code. But right here is where the problem is. in the Database class below. The method "void addCourses(StudentCourse e)". When running the test class. It crashes right after entering a course name, it won't store it like the student name. Im a little new with programming cohesively. Can someone please explain what I am missing?

```
   package student;
   import java.util.ArrayList;


   public class DataBase 
   {
        ArrayList <StudentAccounts> list;
        ArrayList <StudentCourse> courseList;

        StudentAccounts sa ;
        StudentCourse sc;
        int index;
        boolean found = false;

        DataBase()
        {
            list = new ArrayList<> ();  
        }
        ArrayList getList()
        {
            return list;
        }
        ArrayList getCourseList()
        {
            return courseList;
        }
        StudentCourse getCourse(){
            return sc;
        }
        StudentAccounts getAccount()
        {
            return sa;
        }
        StudentAccounts delete (int d) 
        {
            return list.remove(d);
        }

        boolean inList() //Looks in the ArrayList
        {
            return found;
        }
        boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return list.isEmpty();
        }      
        int getIndex()
        {
            return index;
        }
        int getSize() // return the amount of strings in the Array
        {
            return list.size();
        }

         void add(StudentAccounts s)
         {
             list.add(s);
         }
         void addCourse(StudentCourse e)
         {
             courseList.addCourse(e);
         }

         void search(String key)
         {
             found = false;
             int i = 0;

             while (!found && i < list.size() )
             {
                 StudentAccounts sl = list.get(i);
                 if(sl.getStudent().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(key)) 
                 {
                     sa =sl;
                     found = true;      
                     index = i;
                 }
                 else
                     i++;
             }
         }        
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Stack trace? as in explain the process before it crashes? Sure. 

I enter create a new acount >> enter first name, last name, then make an ID number that you can remember. 

Takes you back to the main menu and use that ID number to log in. (This part can store your ID perfectly fine, for if your ID does not match, then you can't continue. 

Once you are logged on, you get option boxes to (exit, , view courses, addCourses, dropCourses)

When i add a course. It crashes and nothing is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized your courseList variable. You have initialized only the one list variable in the constructor Database. When you add a course, the `addCourse()` method will throw a null pointer exception.

Add the following line in your Database constructor:

```
courseList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, the line courseList.addCourse(e) should be a compilation error (so silly of me). courseList is an object of type ArrayList. ArrayList class does not have a method called `addCourse(Studentcourse e)`. It only has a method `add()` which will take an object of type StudentCourse in your case. So you will see a cannot find symbol error.

Change that line to:

```
courseList.add(e);
```

Comment: So under DataBase () { list = new ArrayList<>(); }      I initialize, 
                                    { courseList = new ArrayList <> (); right under it? 

The method still tells me, 

it cannot find symbol: 
symbol :method addCourse(StudentCourse)

Location: variable courseList of type ArrayList <StudentCourse>

Comment: Ah! you have a compilation error because you are trying to call a non existent method. Yes to your first question and I edited the answer for your second

Comment: I can continue this code now! It works! Thank you for your help.